# C# Generic ToString Join if Array or IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have a Generic which hast a string Method. If the Type of the generic is a container (Array, IEnumerable, etc.) their values should be separated by a comma.

```
public class Test<T>
{
    public T GenericProperty { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string ret;
        if (GenericProperty is Array || GenericProperty is IEnumerable)
        {
            ret = String.Join(",", GenericProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            ret = GenericProperty.ToString();
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I want to test it by adding a linq expression (`Select(x => x.ToString()`) to it, but linq isn't available.

When I debug the code above, the if clause is executed properly. But I only get "System.Int32[]" as result.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `T` hasn't any constraints, this line:

```
String.Join(",", GenericProperty);
```

calls this overload:

```
public static string Join(string separator, params object[] values);
```

which causes call to `GenericProperty.ToString()`. You need to call another `Join` overload, which can be achieved this way:

```
        if (GenericProperty is IEnumerable)
        {
            ret = string.Join(",", ((IEnumerable)GenericProperty).Cast<object>());
        }
```

By the way, `is Array` condition isn't necessary, because `Array` implements `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `string.Join` treats `GenericProperty` as `new[] {GenericProperty}` not as collection (see [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword).

Try this code:

```
string.Join(",", ((IEnumerable)GenericProperty).Cast<object>());
```

Answer (score 3):

You're actually using the `String.Join` overload that takes a string and `params object[]` as arguments.

You need to cast GenericProperty to `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
public class Test<T>
{
    public T GenericProperty { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string ret;
        if ( GenericProperty is IEnumerable)
        {
            IEnumerable en = GenericProperty as IEnumerable;
            ret = String.Join(",", en.Cast<object>());

        }
        else
        {
            ret = GenericProperty.ToString();
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```